# callback function inside of controller finishing after ng-options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, d3.js

I parse my data using d3 and a call back function and use a select tag and ng-options to create a dropdown. The problem is the callback function does not finish before the page loads.

Thus, how can I solve this problem of using callback function inside a controller?

For more clarification, if I have a dataset outside the callback function this works and fills my ng-options perfectly.

Comment: Suggest you try splitting this up into two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

How are you routing to the page in the first place? You might want to look into [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) -- and specifically its ability to execute callback functions, [resolve promises](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/) and inject those resolutions into a scope all BEFORE a view is even loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a code example in order to get a specific answer that has has a good chance to be right. If we can't see exactly what you're doing, then we won't be able to tell you what the problem is.

That said, I suspect you're using d3.csv or d3.json (or something similar) to load an external file. These functions use asynchronous callbacks, as opposed to synchronous callbacks, which probably wouldn't cause this sort of problem. I assume that your callback is populating the model of your ng-option on the scope. The issue is that it is executing outside of the Angular context so it doesn't trigger an update cycle.

The solution is either to call your callback logic within a scope.$apply() call (the correct way), or call scope.$digest() at the end of your callback. e.g. do

```
d3.csv(url).get(function(error, rows) {
  scope.$apply(function(scope) {
    // Your logic that updates the scope here.
  });
}
```

That should result in your ng-options being properly updated. If that doesn't work, please provide a working example using something like Plukr or JSFiddle.